# append adding 2 characters to file and string size

Tags: java, server, stringbuilder

I'm reading from a server and this is adding 2  to the length of both the file and the string?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

System.out.print("post first read ");
File temp = new File("temp.html");
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(temp);
//write string to file 
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

while ((nread = reader.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println("post while read " + nread);
    inread = (char) nread;
    bufferedWriter.append(inread);
    sb.append(inread);
}

byteString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @and what exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score -1):

maybe a "\n" (the line feed character) get's added to the end of the strings and it would be better to use reader.readLine() instead of reader.read()

I know this should be a comment but ... not enough reputation :(

Comment: The rules of this forum does not allow comment for new people, there is a reason. And so this is not a reason to give your thought in "answer" because you don't have enough reputation to comment, Vote to close.

Comment: I know there's a reason but... 
I had two options... either strictly follow the rules, make no answer, so don't try to help mKalita at his problem, or slightly violate the rules (which has 0 negative effects for anyone) and try to help him.